# Adding different elements based on button clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have two different panels like this

[image]
.

When i click on the first button, it should display some text, second button should display a datagrid and so on.

How do i change the elements of the right hand panel to achieve this. Initially i just used different windows. Is there a way to call them into the panel ? Then I though of hiding elements based on the button clicked, but that would look like a mess. Should i code the elements when a button is clicked otherwise ? How is this functionality usually added ? What concepts do i need to learn to implement this ?

Answer (score 1):

After coming across this question and seeing the absolutely poor answers that you had been provided with, I felt obliged to offer you a decent answer. There are many different ways of achieving your requirements. Here is probably, the simplest method:

Declare one `Grid` in `MainWindow` that displays your three `Button`s on the left hand side and the three possible controls on the right hand side:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Button" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton Grid.Row="0" Name="Button1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Name="Button2" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Row="2" Name="Button3" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="TextBlock" Text="Here is some text" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding 
        IsChecked, ElementName=Button1, Converter={StaticResource 
        BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="Rectangle" Width="150" Height="40" 
        Fill="LightGreen" Stroke="Black" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=
        Button2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="RadioButton" Content="Here is an 
        option" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{
        Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Button3, Converter={StaticResource 
        BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Note that I used `ToggleButton`s here simply because they have a `bool IsChecked` property that is set when they are clicked on and can be used to show and hide the controls on the right hand side. To do this, we use a [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which was introduced into the .NET Framework in .NET 4.5) to convert our `bool ToggleButton.IsChecked` property values into `Visibility` values.

Now this example probably wasn't exactly what you were thinking of, but I'm sure that it will give you enough of an example for you to experiment with and come up with your desired UI... remember that *you* are going to have to do some work too.

Comment: +1, though it seems you're complicating this a little too much. I'd have used a `TabControl` instead, which scales better since you can add an infinite number of `TabItem`s without all the extra Visibility piping ;)

Answer (score -2):

Create your Xaml page with all the views Textboxt, DataGrid and TextBox2. then you just need to play with the Visibility of controls